# Which way does the referral process work?

Tags: android

I'm working on a app require friend invitation feature. Invited user are transferred to playstore and download app. But I'm not able to fetch which user refer current user. I want to fetch referred user details without filling refer code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER`

`com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER` Intent is broadcast when an app is installed from the Google Play Store.

> 1. Add this receiver to `AndroidManifest.xml.`

```
<receiver
    android:name="your_packagename.InstallReferrerReceiver"
    android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

> 2. Implement BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class InstallReferrerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String referrer = intent.getStringExtra("referrer");

        //Use the referrer
    }
}
```

> 3. Send your app link like.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=your_package&referrer=referrer_code

Comment: Here is complete process of referral process . you can test your code in studio. follow this link   https://github.com/coderminion/AndroidReferrer